# Libgdx - shop scrolling

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm looking for examples to how a shop like in color switch or any other game is made. That you can scroll and if you scroll faster it goes faster, and I have a slight idea that I could calculate this with distance of touch / time, but I like the effect that you can go beyond, but it flicks you back. Or was actually wondering if something like this, which is needed a lot, is already made somewhere in a library?

Comment: I had similar need for my project. I took the time to do a google search found several libraries, I also tried the build in things, but in the end I couldn't find anything flexible enough to fit my needs so I had to create my own scroll suitable for my needs.
It is not hard to implement if you use Tween libraries like http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/projects/universal-tween-engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best recommendation would be to use the built-in `ScrollPane` class along with the other Scene2d.ui components for structuring such a shop window.

Documentation:
https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ScrollPane.html

Comment: Well never used scene2d as I saw no usefullness in it. But gonna try now!